# How to simulate swipe with js-cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, swipe

I have a textarea on my cordova app and a button. Is there a way to simulate the swipe up of the textarea through the button's press? So I don't want to recognize the event, but i want to simulate the swipe up (or swipe down)

Comment: simply use scroll Function to swipe up or swipe down

Comment: The scroll Function only triggers when the element swipes up or down. It doesn't make the element's scroll :(